# Deleting surplus blank lines using Python

Tags: python

I want the Notepad++'s wonderful feature "Delete Surplus blank lines" in Python.

Say if I have file like this

```
A
B


C



D
```

I want

```
A
B

C

D
```

What is the pythonic way of doing this?

Here is what I tried

```
A=['a','\n','\n','\n','a','b','\n','\n','C','\n','\n','\n','\n','\n','\n','D']
B=[]
count=0
for l in range(0,len(A)):
    if A[l]=='\n':
        count=count+1
    else:
        count=0
    if count>1:
        if A[l+1]=='\n':
            continue
        else:   
            B.append('\n')
    else:
        if A[l]!='\n':
            B.append(A[l])
print B
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @RyanSaxe added what I tried, What could be easier way to do this considering new lines are random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one-liner:

```
In [35]: A=['a','\n','\n','\n','a','b','\n','\n','C','\n','\n','\n','\n','\n','\n','D']

In [36]: B = [A[0]] + [A[i] for i in range(1, len(A)) if A[i] != '\n' or A[i-1] != '\n']

In [37]: B
Out[37]: ['a', '\n', 'a', 'b', '\n', 'C', '\n', 'D']
```

It basically omits newlines that follow other newlines.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure there's no more than `\n\n`, eg:

```
import re
print re.sub('\n{3,}', '\n\n', your_string, flags=re.M)
```

And, using `itertools.groupby` for large files:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('your_file') as fin:
    for has_value, lines in groupby(fin, lambda L: bool(L.strip())):
        if not has_value:
            print
            continue
        for line in lines:
            print line,
```

Comment: this is a file though...shouldn't your_string be something more like `file_name.read()`?

Comment: @JonClements thanks for the answer, but in my case new lines may be random, anyway that can be included in your solution.

Comment: @Rajasankar what do you mean by random? And I have a feeling this already does what you're expecting...

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
>>> def delete_surplus_blank_lines(text):
    while '\n\n\n' in text:
        text = text.replace('\n\n\n', '\n\n')
    return text

>>> text = 'a\n\n\nab\n\nC\n\n\n\n\n\nD'
>>> print(text)
a


ab

C





D
>>> print(delete_surplus_blank_lines(text))
a

ab

C

D
>>>
```

A more efficient implementation (based on ideas from NPE) would be:

```
def delete_surplus_blank_lines(text):
    return text[:2] + ''.join(text[index] for index in range(2, len(text))
                              if text[index-2:index+1] != '\n\n\n')
```

A one-liner of that function is fairly easy to create with a `lambda`:

```
delete_surplus_blank_lines = lambda text: return text[:2] + ''.join(text[index] for index in range(2, len(text)) if text[index-2:index+1] != '\n\n\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a file, so lets define a function called `clean_up` to clean up the file you give:

```
def clean_up(file_name,blanks=1):
    with open(file_name,'r+') as f:
        blank = 0
        for line in f:
            if blank < blanks:
                if line == "\n":
                    blank += 1
                f.write(line)
            else:
                blank = 0
                if line != "\n":
                    f.write(line)
```

Now this will iterate through your file, and make sure there are no more than `blanks` number of blank lines in a row!